# Could not initialize class org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory

Tags: java, apache, jboss, httpclient, resteasy

I'm working on webservice and I have a issue like below:

> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.unwrapException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:345)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:321)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:534)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:496)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory
>     org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:487)
>     org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:147)
>     org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:136)
>     org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:112)
>     org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:727)
>     org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:58)
>     com.cns.atta.rest.actions.attaFileUploadActions.uploadToGSFS(attaFileUploadActions.java:443)
>     com.cns.atta.rest.actions.attaFileUploadActions.doRequiredWorks(attaFileUploadActions.java:197)
>     com.cns.atta.rest.actions.attaFileUploadActions.uploadFileXML(attaFileUploadActions.java:89)
>     sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor501.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:255)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:220)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:209)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:496)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

### Please note that the full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/2.1.10 logs.

Library is /jboss-eap-5.1/resteasy/lib/httpclient-4.0.jar"/. Application runs on Jboss 5 EAP server servlet container. It will be deployed to a server as a war file.

In that there is missing class `managedHttpClientConnectionFactory`.

My question is that I can use httpclient-4.3.jar for Jboss 5 EAP right? because in that this class is available or there is another solution to avoid this error.
Any Idea about this?

Code is:

```
Line number 443 :   CloseableHttpClient client =     HttpClients.createDefault();

    try {
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(attaActionContextListener
                .getINSTANCE().getGsfsAddress());
        // Set various attributes
        // FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
        HttpEntity reqEntity = null; ...
```

Line number 197 : parseServerResponse(uploadToGSFS(model, actionType), model);
Line number 89 : return doRequiredWorks(input, ActionType.INSERT);